# How do i turn this into a decrement loop?

Tags: c, loops

```
float batt = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * 5.0; 

demo_printf("Battery:%.2f\n", batt);
```

From the line above , its doing a random numbers for batt. would like to ask how do i do about it to make it as a loop decreasing like very bit by bit . maybe per 0.1.

I cannot for loop the demoprint. i cannot . i can only loop elswhere

Comment: You want the value of `batt` to be a series than decreases (by a random small amount)?

Comment: What do you mean by decrement in this context?  Can you show us the output you want?

Comment: example , now its at random. but i would like it to come in as 5.0 , 4.9 , 4.8 , 4.7

Comment: @RobertLoh You want decreasing random interval or random value, which you got?

Answer (score 1):

```
// obtain initial random float
float batt = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * 5.0;

// iterate beginning with this random float downwards by steps of 0.1f
for (float x = batt; x > 0; x -= 0.1) {
    demo_printf("Battery:%.2f\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code also include an explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: @JonathanMee I provided an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't provide the downvote, cause this answer is as legit as the question can specify, but I will provide a compinsentory upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Huh?

This question is very strange. Do you mean something like this:

```
float batt = 5.f * rand() / RAND_MAX;
while(batt > 0.f)
{
  printf("Battery is %.1f\n", batt);
  batt -= 0.1f;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Battery is 4.2
Battery is 4.1
Battery is 4.0
Battery is 3.9
Battery is 3.8
Battery is 3.7
Battery is 3.6
Battery is 3.5
Battery is 3.4
[ ... more like this ...]
Battery is 1.0
Battery is 0.9
Battery is 0.8
Battery is 0.7
Battery is 0.6
Battery is 0.5
Battery is 0.4
Battery is 0.3
Battery is 0.2
Battery is 0.1
Battery is 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 variables, target and current:

```
float current = 5.0f;
float target = 2.5f;

while(current > target) {
    // print here        
    current -= 0.1f;
}
current = target;
// final print here
```

Just be aware that conversion of float literal constant `0.1f` to binary float will never be perfectly accurate, and the decrement will not be exactly 0.1. But fixing that is for another question.